# Windows 10 Firewall Blocking Incoming VPN Traffic

Tags: windows-server-2016, network-share, windows-10, windows-firewall

Client accesses Windows Server file share and is successful..

```
[Local IP] 192.168.1.62
[VPN IP]   192.168.15.101     --->     [Server IP] 192.168.15.10
                             Success
```

Server side access windows 10 file share and is blocked by the Windows 10 Windows firewall..

```
[Local IP] 192.168.1.62
[VPN IP]   192.168.15.101     <---     [Server IP] 192.168.15.10
                             Blocked
```

The SSL VPN application is identified as a public network by Windows 10.
Inbound firewall rule for the application has been automatically added by the application for itself for all public and private networks.

Disabling Windows 10 Windows firewall works.

Can anyone please advise on allowing this without disabling the firewall? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 firewall, find all the enabled (ticked) rules that start with "File and Printer Sharing...", and individually go into each, and under the "scope" tab change from "Local subnet" to "Any IP Address"